# Problem very often when I start an application as Debug in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019

Very often when I start my application as Debug with Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows Server 2019 machine, I obtain these messages. It happens whatever the application I start in Debug.

The sources of my applications are on the network and I'm running VS2019 on a VMWare virtual machine.

**1st message :**

[image: 1st messsage]

(A debugger operation is taking longer than expected)

**2nd message just after :**

[image: 2nd messsage]

How can I fix these error messages ?

Thanks per advance for your help.

Comment: Is this running on HDD? Is the server used by anyone else or running a major service? Seems to be not enough RAM or an overburdened CPU that makes everything slow and thus system calls timing out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are true I forget to says that the sources of the applications are on the network. For the RAM I have enough and the CPU is not overclocked. My VS 2019 is running on a VMWare virtual machine. I will edit the main post to add these informations.

Comment: I don't mean overclocking, but whether the VM has dedicated cores assigned. Disk I/O is also a concern if there are plenty of other VM running.

Comment: You are sure that it is a hardware problem ? Do I have to ask to the people who manage VMWare to have a look for this problem ?

Comment: Not hardware "problem", but whether enough resources are allocated. If the server is just backed by a couple of disks but there are dozens of active VMs, disk I/O may be too slow for VS. Just benchmark it yourself

Comment: Have you also checked this doc: [Error: Evaluating the function `function` timed out and needed to be aborted in an unsafe way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-evaluating-the-function-function-timed-out-and-needed-to-be-aborted-in-an-unsafe-way?view=vs-2019)?